# Erase comma and apostrophe in character R

Tags: r

I want to remove the comma and the apostrophe but the point of the following character. After that pass to numeric

I have this:

```
characterExample <- "234'564,900.99"
```

I want `234564900.99`

I try the following but I can't:

```
result <- gsub("[:punct:].","", characterExample)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to explicitly remove the characters you want to remove:

```r
gsub("[',]", "", characterExample)
#[1] "234564900.99"
``
```

Comment: Upvoted +1, nice use of brackets, added a similar solution using pipe symbol.

Comment: I like your answer, simple and elegant. Regards "Brigadeiro"

Answer (score 2):

An option is to not match the digits or the `.` by using `^` within the square bracket

```
gsub("[^0-9.]+","", characterExample)
#[1] "234564900.99"
```

---

Or another option is to make use of `SKIP`/`FAIL` for the `.`, while matching the rest of the `punct`

```
gsub("(\\.)(*SKIP)(*F)|[[:punct:]]+", "", characterExample, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "234564900.99"
```

NOTE: Both solutions make sure that it matches any `punct` characters other than the `.` and replace with blank (`""`)

Comment: Great, this is a very good option. Regards

Answer (score 0):

It can also use the pipe symbol like this:

```
#Code
gsub(",|'","", characterExample)
```

Output:

```
gsub(",|'","", characterExample)
[1] "234564900.99"
```